# Pretty Flower Fungus in Oak Tree

Tags: species-identification, mycology

[image]
Found this on a nature walk in the town of Lincoln, MA, USA. Is this edible? I believe it is a type of fungus.

Comment: It is not a good a idea to take advice from the internet about things being edible. Maybe ask for the species first and see whether there is consensus.

Answer (score 3):

> I believe it is a type of fungus.

Yes, this is a kind of fungus. Specifically, I believe it's of the genus *[Laetiporus sp.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laetiporus)*, and is commonly known as "chicken of the woods" and "sulfur shelf". Notice that in both images the mushroom is growing on an [oak tree](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/c0/bf/6a/c0bf6a7c4f22aff15b28daaabe12bdb9--oak-tree-the-beauty.jpg).

[image]

[image]

> Is this edible?

I **strongly** recommend that you watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvbeBEF1cBE) and [this](https://youtu.be/NvCOISKeeKQ?t=3m26s) video. Collectively, they provide more than enough information on how to properly ID the fungus, how to harvest & cook, any potential look-alikes, and even possible medical applications.

***IF*** my suggested identification of your posted organism is correct, then yes, it's edible.

Comment: aka , sulfur polypore.